# Given a stream of numbers how would you keep track of the 1,000,000th largest one?

Tags: algorithm

Given a stream of numbers how would you keep track of the 1,000,000th largest one?

I was asked this in an interview.

Answer (score 14):

One way would be to keep a [minimum heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29), and restrict the heap's size to 1,000,000. While the heap hasn't reached a 1,000,000 items, we'll add each new item from the stream into our heap. When the heap gets full, we'll compare each new item from the stream to the minimum in the heap, and if it's bigger than the minimum, we'll eject the minimum and insert the new item. This way, the heap's minimum item is always the 1,000,000th largest value.

Pseudo code example:

```
Handle_Stream_Item(item):
  if(MinHeap.size < 1000000):
    MinHeap.insert(item)
  else if (item > MinHeap.min()):
    MinHeap.extractMin()
    MinHeap.insert(item)
```

Comment: Minimum heap - that's what I was decribing.  Never knew :)

Comment: Suppose you had N numbers in your stream and you wanted to track the largest C numbers. Note the complexity of this solution is worst case O(n log c). This is always at least as good as worst case O(n log n) since your heap can't have more values than contained in your list of numbers.

Comment: As the algorithm treats c = 1,000,000 as a constant, asymptotically speaking the complexity is n log c = n log 1,000,000 = O(n). The logarithmic part becomes a constant because c is a constant, and therefore the algorithm is linear in time. Space complexity is O(1) for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

As each number is read from the stream, add it to a B-TREE structure.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree

Starting with the million and first number, after adding the new number, remove the right-most (i.e. largest) one from the B-TREE.

At any one time, the right-most number in the B-TREE will be your desired number.

Comment: `Leftmost` and `leftmost` respectively. While this works, the OP needed a 1000000th largest number, and if you will throw away 2000000 largest items, you'll throw the target number as well. This is a minimum heap implementation, while correct, it's redundant to above answers.